# Показ презентации в web

Tags: скрипт, плагин, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Понадобилась необходимость вывести на странице сайта файл из MSOffice презентации (.ppt). Погуглил но ничего не нашел:( Может кто знает какой нибудь скрипт который способен вызвать и воспроизвести презентацию?

Comment: А там (в PowerDot) нет "Сохранить как..." -> "Веб-страница"  (или что-то похожее)? Вроде было. PowerDot'а нет, проверить не могу

Но "Колумбии" уже нет, Вам её не погубить.

Comment: Можно презентацию сохрнаить в PDF и воспользоваться чем-нибудь из этого: http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/javascriptjquery-pdf-viewer-plugins/